# Excel SUM function not working when I have used the IF function to gain results

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using an Excel spreadsheet to automate the results of a table tennis tournament and see who proceeds to the next round.

I have a section of spreadsheet detailing the matches being played with a space for the match results. To the side I have separate section that accumulates players total scores and if they won or lost matches (who goes through is based on total wins).

[image: If image link works, you'll see what I've described above]

I have used the `IF` function to tell my accumulation section to look up each players result and to return a 1 if they won and a 0 if they did not win. The formula I used was `=IF(F4=11,"1","0")`. In this case cell `F4` is one of the match scores for Simon Westbrook. This part is working fine.

However, my Total column in the accumulation section has stopped working (again, if image link above has worked, you'll see where I mean).

Before I input the 1s and 0s for wins / losses manually and the total column had the `SUM` function of (as example) `=SUM(O4:Q4)`. Based on linked image, this previously would have returned a result of 2.

Since including the `IF` function to automate wins / losses, the `SUM` formula has stopped working. I have checked all cells are number. I have also dragged mouse across cells to see what comes up in that 'Sum' box at the bottom of excel sheet...it stayed at zero when I scrolled over my win / loss boxes.

I have also tried opening the formula toolbox to see if Excel can suggest a fix. Under the arguments within toolbox the formula shows {"1","0","1"} but with a result of 0.

Can anyone suggest an alternative formula to `SUM` when you're trying to total rows that are using the `IF` formula, or a way to tell Excel to recognise the numbers in the win / loss boxes?

First time user on here, so apologies for length of question and if not formatted entirely correctly.

Comment: I can't follow that link from the firewall I'm behind, but I feel like the "Sumifs" command might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Using the quotes force a string instead of a number, try using `=IF(F4=11,1,0)`

Comment: [We prefer that you not post images that represent only textual data (even spreadsheets).](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/80216 "Please don’t post images of text")  But what’s worse is that your illustration doesn’t really *illustrate* anything.  Row 4 (columns `D:F` and `L:R`) contains the data (match scores) for Simon Westbrook.  Ho hum.  `F4` (Simon Westbrook’s score) is 11.  OK.  `=IF(F4=11,"1","0")` appears to evaluate to `1`.  OK, but where?  `O4`? `Q4`?  You’ve got a `SUM()` of a range of three cells that appear to contain `1`, `0` and `1`, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  and the sum (in cell `R4`?) contains `0`. OK; that’s the issue.  What does your screenshot show or even clarify?  (And why do you have `N7` selected?)  … … … … … … … … …  P.S. What your picture does show is that you have `=SUM(J5+J6+J9)` in `N7`.  (1) This is equivalent to `=J5+J6+J9`.  You are calling `SUM()` with one argument.  (2) I notice that cells `J5`, `J6` and `J9` are all associated with “Richard Marsh”.  So you build the formulas in Column `N` manually based on which names are in which rows?  You should use `SUMIF` to add all the values (scores) that correspond to a name.

Comment: @AFH: “Because it’s there” is not sufficient reason to inline an image.  Not all images need to be in-lined (see above).

Comment: @G-Man - I made the image in-line, because I was finding it difficult to follow the text when swapping between browser tabs. The fact that the image turns out to be unhelpful is not a reason for making the question less easy to read.

Comment: @AFH: And my point is that in-lining the image *doesn’t* make the question easier to read or to understand.  (1) The inline version is so shrunken that it’s almost impossible to read.  (But maybe you have a larger display than I do, or better eyes.) (2) I don’t see any useful information in the image that isn’t adequately and clearly explained by the text.  (Maybe I understand English better than you do.)

Comment: @G-Man - (1) I retained the link, so you can still click on the image to show the full image if you need to, although you can also zoom the whole page (`Ctrl-+` on Firefox) and both text and image are enlarged. (2) Your conclusion is easier to reach and confirm when both text and image are visible at the same time. (I was educated in Scotland and my mother was an English teacher, so my understanding of English is not lacking, though I did struggle a bit to relate the questioner's text to the image, hence my embedding in-line.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As cybernetic.nomad says](https://superuser.com/q/1318857/150988#comment1964543_1318857), quotes give you strings (text values). 
Strings whose values look like numbers are weird —
sometimes you can do arithmetic with them, and sometimes you can’t. 
In particular, `SUM` seems not to work.

Unless you have a really *really **really*** good reason for using strings,
you should just stick with numbers and say `=IF(F4=11, 1, 0)`.

Comment: Thank you to those who gave responses...the suggestion of removing the quote marks worked and now I feel like a fool as the fix was so simple. Again...thank you

Comment: Your formula is an unnecessary elaboration of `=F4=11`.